# How to draw a Polygon with X sides (all equal length & angles)

Tags: java, math, polygon

I am looking to calculate the X and Y points of each point on a polygon, given the number of sides, and the fact that all sides are equal.  I would also have the width and height constraints of the entire shape.  If it helps any, I would be doing this in Java (most likely using Line2D).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should first find out the center of the circle (cx, cy) and the radius R by the width and height constraints, which is trivial. Each of the polygon points is equally distributed on the circle and their position can be calculated by:

```
Xi = cx + R*cos(2.0*PI*i/n)
Yi = cy + R*sin(2.0*PI*i/n)
```